# Count with condition and subsections

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, excel-formula

First of all sorry if my english isn't the best, I'm not a native ^^

I have, for a project, to create a table like this one :

[image]

The first column are big sections. Each section have a number of sub-section (Named idea on the screenshot) and each subsection has a "o" or "n" value linked in the third column.

My goal is to count the number of big section where one of its subsession has the "o" value. To be more clear, only the big section "number 3" don't have a sub-section with a "o" value, so the value counted should be 3.

Do you guys know a formula to have this, for exemple with a "for" loop in the sub-section to check if there is a "o" value? Or is it too complex for classic excel and i should use VBA?

Hope my problem is clear ^^ if not feel free to ask :)

Thanks a lot and have a good day !!

Comment: Are the cells in the first column merged cells?

Comment: Can you include your own attempt to make this on-topic?

Comment: Yes they are merged!

Comment: Maybe try like this : `sub test`, next line `Dim oStart As Range: dim cnt as long`, next line `Set oStart = Range("a1")`, next line `do`, next line `If Not Range(oStart, oStart.End(xlToRight)).Find("o", lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then cnt = cnt + 1` , next line `Set oStart = oStart.Offset(1, 0)`, next line `Loop Until oStart.Value = ""`, next line `MsgBox "The total count of big section which has letter o is " & cnt`, next line `end sub`. The sub assumed that the big section is column A starts from the first row.

Comment: (What about subtotals?)[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-7881d256-b4fa-4f81-b71e-b0a3d4a52b3a]

Answer (score 0):

or older version:
[image]

```
=COUNT(MATCH(LEFT(A1,7)&ROW(1:9)&"o",LOOKUP(ROW(1:11),ROW(1:11)/(A1:A11<>""),A1:A2)&C1:C11,))
```

M365 version:
[image]

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(SCAN(,A1:A11,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),C1:C11="o")))
```